# Can I label browser tabs across-origins?

Tags: html

I have a number of embedded devices with a web-based front end, each on a different randomly assigned ip address.

I often want to check between these devices but, when they're open in different tabs, it is hard to tell which is which.

I have attempted to embed these pages in iframes with a header labelling each one, but CORS prevented the pages from showing.

Is there a way I could get the opening page to label a tab or window to help me distinguish between similar looking pages?  Failing that, and possibly in SuperUser territory, is there any way I could manually label the tabs in my browser once they're open?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a partial answer.  There are a number of third-party plugins for Chrome which allow the user to manually rename tabs.  I have installed one called Simple Tab Renamer and it seems to be doing the job.

An automated system would be nicer, but I suspect security policies would prevent that.

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/simple-tab-renamer/ailhpmlejogfdcpoflidmobgkgdemaog